# Populate inside nested array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, populate

I am populating an array of characters and each character has its class and race as a reference to an object. What is the right populate query to get both, race and class. Thank you for your answers

```
UserModel.
findOne({ Something: 'Something' })
populate({
    path: "characters",
    populate:{
        path: "class, race"
    }
})
.exec(function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs.characters[1]);
    console.log(err);
});
```

-- Changed the endings of the models and now it works.

```
UserModel.
    findOne({ Something: 'Something' })
    .populate({
        path: "characters",
        model: 'Characters',
        populate: [{
            path: 'class',
            model: 'Classes'
        },
        {
            path: 'race',
            model: 'Races'
        }]
    })
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs.characters[1]);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
UserModel.
    findOne({ Something: 'Something' })
    .populate({
        path: "characters",
        model: 'Character',
        populate: [{
            path: 'class',
            model: 'Class'
        },
        {
            path: 'race',
            model: 'Race'
        }]
    })
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs.characters[1]);
        console.log(err);
    });
```